# return direct reference to static function in PHP

Tags: php, function, reference

Now to return reference to static function I return reference to closure (inside boot function). Closure just calls static function.

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    private static function createEloquentLdapProvider($app) {...}

    public function boot()
    {
        Auth::extend('databaseLdapCredentials', function($app) {
            return self::createDatabaseLdapProvider($app);
        });
    });
}
```

In C# I can return direct reference to static function by the name. I try to use function name in PHP also:

```
    public function boot()
    {
        Auth::extend('databaseLdapCredentials', self::createDatabaseLdapProvider);
    });
```

But it does not works. PHP thinks that `self::createDatabaseLdapProvider` is static variable (not reference to static function).

So how I can return direct reference to static function in PHP and do not use closure, that is crutch in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a mistake you must use $this as a:

```
return this->createDatabaseLdapProvider($app);
```

Comment: `createDatabaseLdapProvider` is static function!

Comment: can you try this:    public static  function example2(){
    echo 'hello';
}

    public function example1(){
        $this->example2();
  }